# How to remove gaps between objects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I have this map of Europe, and my problem with it is that there is white space between the country shapes after I removed the outline.

[image]

I want the paths of the different countries to fit perfectly to each other. The simplest solution I thought of would be making all the countries 2% larger so the paths overlap and you use trim on that.

How do you make objects larger in every direction? Or is there a better solution where you can have the paths calculate half the distance between each other and come together in the middle?

Comment: Have you tried selecting all the countries, then in Pathfinder click on Union?

Answer (score 2):

- Select the shapes and add a **Stroke**
- **Align Stroke** = **Outside**

[image: *Align Stroke]

- **Menu Object** > **Expand Appearance**
- With the **Direct Selection Tool** select the inner part of the shapes > Delete
- With the **Direct Selection Tool** and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> to select the whole path, select the inner part of the frames > Delete

[image: bigger]

Comment: Yes, but with a different procedure, it is another question and another answer: How to make objects larger in some direction?

Comment: Yes: it's possible to do that, but the solution it is not with a stroke, is with a different procedure. Different question, different procedure, different answer.